# Travis cmd command

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

How can I use cmd command in my .travis.yml? I need to execute a 'cd' before install my package & execute my server. Here is my .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js: 
- 6
services:
- mongodb
install: npm install
script: npm start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `before_install`, please check the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/) of travis:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 6
services:
  - mongodb
before_install: cd ./path
install: npm install
script: npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

`before_install` should work in this case.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this answer - perhaps show the where that fits into the script?

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.